# Chrome Extension: Not loading source-maps

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I am not able to load sourcemap in Chrome Extension for some reason.

The folder which is being loaded for Chrome Extension has `.map` just next to `.js` file. With the `.js` file having the line `//# sourceMappingURL=1.9215106f1980d05d2b4c.js.map` referencing the .map file path.

However, the Chrome dev-tools is not loading the maps for some reason.

I double checked the Chrome settings to make sure that the js source maps is turned on and it is working with a simple Angular project.

Also, made sure I have the following in the manifest file:

```
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "*.map"
  ],
```

Comment: hi there, did you find out how to load source maps?

Answer (score 1):

Attention! This code is meant for development purposes and not meant for production environments, as it makes use of eval. Mozilla does recomment not to use this.

Setting the following property in webpack.config.js worked for me:

```
module.exports = {
    //Configuration parameters

    devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    //Other configuration parameters
}
```

Edit: You'll also have to update manifest.json to allow `eval`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

List of devTool styles:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool

webpack.config.js explained:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: it didn't work for me. Moreover, extensions can't use 'eval'  according to: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy

Comment: ok found the solution, you have to add   "content_security_policy" to manifest, I'll edit the answer

Comment: bArmageddon Thanks for the hint. I forgot about that.

Comment: This may no longer work in manifest v3 since it is not possible to include `unsafe-eval`